# Simple libs for trajectory motion in Flex Builder (mxml, actionscript)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml, motion

I need a simple rainbow trajectory motion in Flex builder.

We have 2 points [(x1, y1); (x2, y2)], we need to animate object from one to another over some simple rainbow trajectory like in this picture in 10 seconds

[image]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://superior0.narod.ru/CO/mtw.jpg))</sub>

What libs could you suggest for such an operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like TweenMax a lot. It is very simple to use. For your scenario you can probably move along a bezier curve, which they also support.

http://blog.greensock.com/tweenmax/